# How to see what rotation an orthogonal matrix represents?

Tags: linear-algebra, rotations, orthogonal-matrices

As the output to some calculation I get an orthogonal 2-D matrix, which I know must represent some 2-D rotation (and possibly a reflection). It looks like

\begin{bmatrix}
f & g \newline
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}

Where $f$ and $g$ are complicated trig functions. In case it is important this comes out of the singular-value decomposition of another matrix. If I am to just naïvely compare this to a general rotation matrix

\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\theta & -\sin\theta \newline
\sin\theta & \cos\theta
\end{bmatrix}

I get $\cos\theta=\sin\theta$ so $\theta=\pi/4$ (the matrix has some missing overall constant). The problem is that I have physical reasons for thinking this can't be right.

Is there a way that this might represent a matrix for a different rotation? (Possibly also involving a reflection?)

Comment: This matrix can never be orthogonal. The columns, for starters, must be unit vectors. Then they must be orthogonal to one another.

Comment: @TedShifrin Hey, thanks, but I checked and indeed they are orthogonal. The missing thing is that $fg=-1$

Comment: But unit vectors are required for an orthogonal matrix!

Comment: Like I mentioned there is some overall constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Ted Shifrin pointed out, the matrix explicitly given cannot be orthogonal, because the second row is not a unit vactor.  The only scalars $\ c\ $ for which the matrix
$$
c\begin{bmatrix}
f&g\\1&1
\end{bmatrix}\tag{1}\label{e1}
$$
can be orthogonal are $\ c=\pm2^{-\frac{1}{2}}\ $, and then you would need $\ fg=-1\ $ (which you have acknowledged to hold) *and* $\ f^2+g^2=2\ $.  Combining these two restrictions on $\ f\ $ and $\ g\ $ gives you
$$
f^2+\frac{1}{f^2}=2\ ,
$$
or, equivalently,
\begin{align}
0&=f^4-2f^2+1\\
&=\big(f^2-1\big)^2\ ,
\end{align}
so $\ f^2=1\ $. Thus, the only orthogonal matrices of the form \ref{e1} are
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}
1&-1\\1&1
\end{bmatrix},\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}
-1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix},\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}
-1&1\\-1&-1\end{bmatrix}
$$
and
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}
1&-1\\-1&-1\end{bmatrix}\ .
$$